# GoogleSignIn iOS framework no Bitcode support

Tags: ios, google-signin, bitcode

I would really like to include Bitcode support for my iOS project but I am using the Google Sign In framework and it looks like they STILL haven't added Bitcode support to the library.

I cannot seem to find any information about whether this is coming soon or much talk about how other developers are demanding this feature... am I the minority here? Does nobody else use the Google Sign In framework in iOS or do they just not want to use Bitcode?

I would remove the Google Sign In framework as it has been nothing but trouble for me, but I am afraid that 7% of my users registered with Google Sign In so I am now stuck with it.

I am using the pods:

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

GoogleAnalytics seems to be fine now and have BitCode support but the GoogleSignIn framework still gives errors when Bitcode is turned on such as:

> ...Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Libraries/libGTMOAuth2_external.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems like "Sign In" library doesn't support BitCode at this moment. But, you always can disable it, because Bitcode is optional as Apple says in its notes:

> For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide
>   bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include
>   bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.

So, you just need to disable it:

1. Select your target.
2. Go to Build Settings.
3. Search "bit code".
4. Change "Enable Bitcode" option to NO.

[image: Xcode Project]

I.

Comment: I obviously have BitCode turned off at the moment because as I say above I use the Google Sign In framework. What my post was about was wanting to turn it on and how I cannot because Google don't support it in this framework.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sign In v 3.0.0 now has BitCode support!

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release